# App Engine - GQL invalid query string

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I don't know what can be wrong here:

```
SELECT * FROM RGUser    
WHERE isGuest = FALSE AND created < DATE('2011-09-01')    
ORDER BY created
```

screenshot http://my.jetscreenshot.com/3910/20110904-pwms-18kb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in your query, it's just the datastore viewer that does not work well in case of query modification after an error; just to copy the query, click again on Datastore viewer, paste it and launch it again.